# Have to send values in placeholder for Name and Email using protractor

Tags: javascript, polymer, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Following is the HTML where we have placeholder for name and email

```
<section slot="drawer" for="account" class="iron-selected">
    <form class="form ng-pristine ng-valid">
      <h4>CONTACT US</h4>
      <p type="Name:"><input placeholder="Write your name here.."></p>
      <p type="Email:"><input placeholder="Let us know how to contact you back..">
      </p>
      <button>Send Message</button>
    </form>
  </section>
```

Comment: What's the exact question?

Comment: @wswebcreation : I want to send values in placeholder of Name and Email using protractor

Comment: Do you want to change the attribute values of the `placeholder`-attribute, or do you want to send data to the input field?

Comment: Yes, I want to send data

Comment: Just curious, but why? That should be a unit test, not a UI test because a user can never change the `placeholder`-attribute

Comment: I wanted to send values to test end to end values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142498/discussion-between-wswebcreation-and-abbas-ali).

Comment: Down voted the question because it's not clear. Only after extra questions and a chat. Advice is to rethink the way you are asking a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you exactly want to change.

**Change the value of the attribute**

Changing the value of an attribute can be done with "pure" javascript. This can be done with the `browser.executeScript('your javascript code here');`, docs can be found [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript)

Take in consideration that changing an *attribute*-value:

- is in my opinion a unit test, not a UI test
- can never be changed by a user through the UI (only if he uses developer tools)
- *a placeholder is a hint to the user of what can be entered in the control . The placeholder text must not contain carriage returns or line-feeds. 
  Note: Do not use the placeholder attribute instead of a  element, their purposes are different. The  attribute describes the role of the form element (i.e. it indicates what kind of information is expected), and the placeholder attribute is a hint about the format that the content should take. There are cases in which the placeholder attribute is never displayed to the user, so the form must be understandable without it.* ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) and search for placeholder)

**Change input**

If you would like to send a value (so not changing the `placeholder`-attribute) you can use the `sendKeys()`-method. More info about how to use it look [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys)

In your case you first need to identify the element you want to send the value to. It would be nice that the `input`-element you need to send a value to has an unique selector. But with the code you gave you can solve it with this

```
// Because you can't select the input directly we can access it by it's parent
// `p` tag and then go to the input
element(by.css('p[type="Name:"] input')).sendKeys('my name is');
element(by.css('p[type="Email:"] input')).sendKeys('e.mail@example.com');
```

At last you need to submit your form by clicking on the `button`. Because your `button` doesn't have an unique selector you can use the [`by.buttonText`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.buttonText) method. This isn't a recommended method because you don't want to find elements based on their text. But for now u can do this

```
element(by.buttonText('Send Message'));
```

Your complete script will become

```
element(by.css('p[type="Name:"] input')).sendKeys('my name is');
element(by.css('p[type="Email:"] input')).sendKeys('e.mail@example.com');
element(by.buttonText('Send Message'));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You rock , i am able to send values to controls , thanks for help

Comment: Welcome, if the answer helped it would be nice if you accept it as the answer. Tnx in advance